# Can't figure out how to properly type my N-ary tree

Tags: haskell

I made the following N-ary tree data type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
```

with the following method:

```
listLeaf::Tree a -> [a]
listLeaf (Leaf a) = [a]
listLeaf (Node a (l:list)) = concat $ listLeaf l
```

I'm trying to make listLeaf so that it gives me a list that contains each element of a leaf inside my tree. This means that if I have the following tree: `Node 3 [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Node 1 [Leaf 3]]`, my objective would be to get [1,2,3].

As you probably noticed the type of my function doesn't add up because it expects a list of a, but I'm giving it a list of lists.
Can't wrap my head around how I can have the base case (leaf) return me a type [a] and at the same time have the Node case give me the same kind of type. I feel like I need to use a higher order function aside from concat, but I got no clue.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are here only calling `listLeaf` on `l`, the first element of the list, so you will only obtain the *leftmost* leaf. Furthermor `concat` then does not make much sense, ince you have a list of values, not a list of lists of values.

You can use [**`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) to perform a mapping on all elements and concatenate the lists of the results, so:

```
listLeaf :: Tree a -> [a]
listLeaf (Leaf a) = [a]
listLeaf (Node _ cs) = concatMap listLeaf cs
```